# How to automatically start a new line by "looking at the width" of the screen in a kivy label?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm building a kivy app,that does research on wikipedia and shows on a Label the results...How can I start a new line,respecting the width of the screen and starting a new line "automatically".Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the kv rule, use:

```
    text_size: self.size
```